# CloudWatch Custom logs are not rendering properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

When I try to push my IIS or MSSQL logs into CloudWatch, I can see logs in the server are appearing however they are in the single line in CW where as in the servers they are two different events with different timestamp

I've treid using  `"multi_line_start_pattern": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` however this doesn't solve my problem

CloudWatch Json file:

```
{
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Id": "IISLogs",
        "Parameters": {
          "CultureName": "en-US",
          "Encoding": "UTF-8",
          "Filter": "",
          "LineCount": "5",
          "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\logfiles",
          "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
          "TimestampFormat": "\\%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\"  (also tried  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format)
        }
      },


{
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Id": "CloudWatchIISLogs",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogGroup": "/application/iis",
          "LogStream": "{instance_id}",
          "Region": "eu-west-1",
          "multi_line_start_pattern": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
```

under flows:

"(IISLogs),CloudWatchIISLogs",

Logs I see in CW: I see its not finding difference between each end line, however in the IIS server I do have the logs seperated in next line. same is happening for MSSQL.

I would expect the logs to be pushed into the CW same as mentioned in the server/instance unlike below:

Under time: I have the timestamp:

Under Message:  this is coming under single message where as it consists of multiple messages (3 events of user1)

```
2019-05-31 12:19:42 ::1 GET / - 80 user ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 2032019-05-31 12:19:43 ::1 GET / - 80 user1 ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 152019-05-31 12:19:43 ::1 GET /libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js - 80 user1 ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/ 304 0 0 02019-05-31 12:19:43 ::1 GET /libs/canvg/canvg.js - 80 user1 ::1
```

status code is merging with the next line which is date/time due to which logs are not showing/split up properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have got an answer to this, this was due to the agent that we were using - SSM, post migration to CW agent its resolved.